# How to pass data to DataContext?

Tags: leaflet, esri, esri-maps, esri-leaflet, esri-javascript-api

I have a list of zip codes to loop over to get the lat/lng. How do I pass the object **zip** to the "success" method so I can assign the lat/lng to the right **zip** object? Right now by the time I get the results back, I assign them to the wrong **zip** :-(

I believe the response is the dataContext object but when I tried { zip : zip }, it didn't work. The response contains no such property.

```
for (var j = 0; j < zipList.length; j++) {
    var zip = zipList[j];
    L.esri.Geocoding.geocode().postal(zip.Zipcode).run(function (err, results, response) {
       alert(response.zip);
  }, { zip : zip });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the code used to fetch geo location is running asynchronous. I would suggest you to first get all geo location using some waiting loop. Once you get all lat lon than use the forloop to update dB.